# Ajax UpdatePanel not firing?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am not understanding why this doesn't fire. It will not even call the event. Any thoughts? Really what I want to do, is prevent a full post-back. The page is large and each time it does a post back it jumps to the top.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate>

    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSnippet" AssociatedControlID="cmbSnippet">

            From snippet:

        </asp:Label>

        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbSnippet" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>
                None
            </asp:ListItem>

            <asp:ListItem>
                Read Part
            </asp:ListItem>

            <asp:ListItem>
                Read Feed
            </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </p>

    <!--Code-->

    <p>    
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCode" AssociatedControlID="txtCode">

            From code:

        </asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCode" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="editor" MaxLength="100" Height="200" Wrap="false" />
    </p>  

    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>

         <asp:Asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="cmbSnippet" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />

    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: For some reason its chopping off this line on stack-overflow:  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">

Comment: Include your updatepanel opening-tag so we can see the options you have.

Comment: I did in the comment above. Unless its chopping it off. It is running at the server and the updatemode=conditional.

Comment: What the `<!-- code --> contains ? because if contain actually csharp code this is the reason that is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

you have not declared the event
something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbSnippet" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbSnippet_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and his relative handler in codebehind...